# Selectively restore from a time machine backup created on snow leopard to a different machine running mountain lion

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a current time machine backup on USB from an older machine running snow leopard 10.6. How can I selectively restore applications and data from this time machine disk to a new mac running Mountain Lion 10.8?

Comment: Also found that I need to use `vsdbutil` from http://superuser.com/a/276526/4324 to resolve permission issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy folders and files from `/Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/` normally. Finder and `cp` don't preserve hard links.